# Ruby on Rails: I need to invoke an observer_field when I programmatically change the value of a select, how can I do that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

This part works:

```
<%= observe_field "dbe_filter", :url => {:action => :filter_action, :only_path => :false },
                  :frequency => 0.5,
                    :with => "'value='+encodeURIComponent(value)"%>
```

My javascript: this part works

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $j("#dbe_filter").change(function(){
    $stored_filter = $j(this).val();
  });
  $j("#dbe_filter").val($stored_filter);
  // what I want is something right here that will invoke the above 
  //   observe_field helper. 
  // Is there a way with jQuery (i'm using noConflict) to invoke a .change
  //   action?

  // current, non-working solution (node that the alert pops up):
   alert($stored_filter + " " + $j("#dbe_filter").val());
    $j("#dbe_filter").trigger('change');
  // assuming a solution works, I should see a proper XHR request in the webkit inspector.

</script>
```

The details of what is happening: I have a different select drop down, that re-renders part of a page, and upon re-rendering, all the new javascript is ran (hence why my alert message test works), but I don't understand why the .trigger doesn't.  I need change triggered, so that a different part of my code is triggered to draw a graph.

I'm surprised that changing the value of the select with javascript doesn't trip the 'change' trigger

The .trigger works. Just needs to be placed after the observe_field helper. 
• This question is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

```
$j("#dbe_filter").trigger('change');
```

I would suggest using this code to test if it works:

```
<select id='dbe_filter'>
  <option value='NEW'>NEW</option>
  <option value='UPDATED'>UPDATED</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#dbe_filter").change(function(){
    $(this).val("UPDATED");
  });

  $("#dbe_filter").trigger('change');

</script>
```

Comment: @Pan Thomakos, So, the inspector from webkit says that it isn't working. I know the area of code is working because of an alert message. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: I was able to get the test code to work, so your issue might not be with triggering the change event.

Comment: thats exactly whats wrong. The details of what is happening: I have a different select drop down, that re-renders part of a page, and upon re-rendering, all the new javascript is ran (hence why my alert message test works), but I don't understand why the .trigger doesn't.  I need change triggered, so that a different part of my code is triggered to draw a graph.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish here.  You might want to try including some error message or a more detailed code selection.  My recommendation would be to run a debugger or simplify your code and verify that the actual operations you are performing work in the simplest case.  Check the Ruby part first, then check the Javascript part separately and make sure that each is working individually before trying to have them interact.

Comment: @Pat Thomakos: I'm surprised that changing the value of the select with javascript doesn't trip the 'change' trigger

Comment: I think that's because the change action is reserved for the user actually performing that action.  Also, modifying the value does not actually mean that the value has changed, it could be exactly the same.

Comment: Well, the app I'm working on is kinda complicated to explain, and it's private, so I can't release any of it. But I just need a way to trigger the observer_field helper so that it can GET data from my server, and AJAXily update the chart.

Comment: Like, I have two filters, one is a date-time filter, and the other is various stats that can be looked at for my data (this is the filter I'm trying to trigger).  The first filter does a replace_html on the chart, and because I've stored the previous filter state to a $global_variable, I can set the second filter to the value it was before, but the observer_field helper is never tripped, so the chart doesn't also update.

Comment: As I mentioned before, without additional code you'll only be getting guesses at what the problem is. As for triggering the change event, at least you know that part works. The code I posted is the simplest version of it. Do the same for your code, test it, make sure you are doing things correctly. Try debugging - it works. Be patient and good luck.

Comment: As it turned out, it was something stupid. You're answer does exactly what I need, I just need to have the call after the observe_field helper.... bah. No me gusta simple mistakes.